# PHP get checkbox value in checked/unchecked

Tags: php, mysql

```
<?php

// $groups is fetch_array from mysql
foreach($groups as $group) {
    if ($group['delete_user'] === 'Y') {
        $checked = "checked=\"checked\";
    }
    else {
        $checked = '';
    }
?>
    <input type = "checkbox" name="delete_user[<?php echo $group['id']; ?>]" <?php echo $checked; ?>>
<?php

}
?>
```

Will output:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete_user[1]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete_user[2]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete_user[3]">
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete_user[4]" checked="checked">
    <input type="submit" name="save_action" value="Save">
</form>
```

And when I check inputs as wanted, then this will process input.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save_action']) {
    if (empty($_POST['delete_user'])) {
        $_POST['delete_user'] = array();
    }
    foreach($_POST['delete_user'] as $del) {
        is_checked($del); //@todo 
    }
}
?>
```

I am looking for way to check if check-box is checked and return proper value ( Y or N ). In this point I declared is_checked() function for this purpose.

Comment: $_POST['delete_user'] will only contain those that have been checked.

Comment: Well, by then nature of how HTML forms work, it is only going to POST values of checkboxes that are checked.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete_user[]" value="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete_user[]" value="2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete_user[]" value="3">
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete_user[]" value="4" checked="checked">
    <input type="submit" name="save_action" value="Save">
</form>
```

Now in PHP you can loop over the $_POST['delete_user'] and it will contain the values of the selected items.

```
foreach($_POST['delete_user'] as $item)
{
   // code to delete $item
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As the comments already mentioned, only the checked checkboxes will be set
So you either have to take the index as ID or add a val to each input element.
The latter would probably be cleaner (in my opinion)

```
<?php
// $groups is fetch_array from mysql
foreach($groups as $group) {
    if ($group['delete_user'] === 'Y') {
        $checked = "checked=\"checked\";
    }
    else {
        $checked = '';
    }
?>
    <input type = "checkbox" name="delete_user[]" <?php echo $checked; ?> value="<?php echo $group['id'];?>">
<?php
}
?>
```

And the code which does something with the inputs:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['save_action']) {
    if (empty($_POST['delete_user'])) {
        $_POST['delete_user'] = array();
    }
    foreach($_POST['delete_user'] as $del) {
        // do something with $del - the id
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the checkbox name just as an array and then give the id as value. See the below code.

```
<?php
// $groups is fetch_array from mysql
foreach($groups as $group) {
 if ($group['delete_user'] === 'Y') {
    $checked = "checked=\"checked\";
 }
 else {
    $checked = '';
 }
?>
 <input type = "checkbox" name="delete_user[]" value="<?php echo $group['id']; ?>" <?php echo $checked; ?>>
<?php

}
?>
```

Then on the action page place this code

```
<?php
      foreach($_POST['delete_user'] as $del) {
      is_checked($del); //@todo 
   }
}
?>
```

This will work fine.